Is session string considered a sensitive information in AWS Cognito custom authentication flow?
I'm working on implementing OTP (One Time Password) authentication using AWS Cognito.
This involves setting up two endpoints. The first endpoint generates a session string which is then used by another endpoint. My understanding is that this session string serves as a connection point to track the current authentication state in Cognito. Specifically, the session string is required by the RespondToAuthChallengeCommand in the following code snippet:
const command = new RespondToAuthChallengeCommand({
  ClientId: "<CLIENT_ID>",
  ChallengeName: "CUSTOM_CHALLENGE",
  ChallengeResponses: {
    USERNAME: "<PHONE_NUMBER>",
    ANSWER: "<CODE>"
  },
  Session: "<SESSION>" // <- HERE
})

Here's how the session is obtained and used in pseudo JavaScript code:
// Endpoint to initiate authentication flow
const response = await fetch("/sign-in", { 
  method: "POST",
  body: { 
    phoneNumber: "123456789"
  }
})

// Response contains session string
response.json() // { "session": "AYABeL-0MC--pl68FiWpwBg7FckAHQABA..." }

// Endpoint to submit OTP along with session for authentication
const response = await fetch("/code-confirmation", { 
  method: "POST",
  body: { 
    "phoneNumber": "123456789", 
    "code": "abc", 
    "session": "AYABeL-0MC--pl68FiWpwBg7FckAHQABA..." // <- HERE
  }
})

My main question is whether it's safe and acceptable to pass this session string to the client, or if it should be stored on the backend during the authentication flow?
P.S. As you can see in my current implementation I do pass the session string back to the client and ask him to put this session string when calling another endpoint.
